# Override list item background color with white, keep system default (long)pressed color

Tags: android, android-listview, android-styles, android-selector

How can I replace the color of a listview item background when in the non-(focused|pressed|activated) state with a custom color, but keep all the system default colors for pressed, long-pressed, activated, focused etc. states?

I'm trying to give my listviews a *card* style - that is white items with space in between on a grey background (as in *Google Play Store* app and others).

So I want to give the items a **white** background, but at the same time, keep all the system default selectors, including the fade animation for long press. That is, I want to replace the **transparent** color for the inactive states with **white**, but keep all the other states as by default.

This is even more important since the *KitKat* release, because all the accents have now switched from **blue** to **grey**, so I would like the app to respect that - to have **blue** color when pressed on *ICS* and *JellyBean*, but **grey** on *KitKat*. Therefore, I don't want to hard-code any values into a custom selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I figured it out and it's incredibly simple:

All I have to do is to add this attribute to the given `ListView`:

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
```

And that's all! I can give the list items any background color that I want and it will always be overlayed by the system default selector!

Comment: In my almost-identical case (on ICS/ JB) this resulted in a list item that retained its state but not while being pressed. Click list item -> (no change in display) -> launch activity -> return -> list item shows as pressed/ selected. Any ideas why?